# drupal 7 using sqlserver database is slow

Tags: sql-server, drupal-7

I were deployed website using drupal 7 and sql server. Its has no problem in my local server (webmatrix), but on live server, its too slow to access database, anyone have experience with that?

thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal 7 is generarly slower, but, you should check if indexes were created

Comment: oh damn, yups man. Thanks You @rotar-radu, i'm to forget for indexing the database. :)

Comment: How exactly did you index the database?